# Security system design in MVC application

Tags: security, model-view-controller, web-applications

Which design approach can be used, already exists or new ones to implement security system in MVC web-application?

Possibly there are patterns, best practices, e.g. in some popular languages, e.g. Java, .Net or whatsoever?
On which level is it better to implement it: model or controller or something between them?

I faced that primitive approach results in spreading security checks among many controllers or models depending on implementation, mixing with code of levels.
But it is not obvious for me in which way to design security in better way.

I have an MVC application.
I need flexible system of access rights.
I have and hierarchy of categories and entities in categories.
Some user can edit/view/add/remove one on set of categories, another users - other categories.
It is also required that depending on user role some fields of model should not be retrieved from DB (null should be returned)
Admins should be able to assign different access rights.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using .Net's built in member ship providers. By default a new MVC 3 Internet Application Visual Studio project template will give you basic login code. Clicking on the 'manage' your site button from within visual studio will give you the web interface to manage the users and roles. Create your users/roles, then define [Authorize(Roles="Admin,Users")] on your Controller class definition or on your method definitions. DO NOT define URL access as was done in Asp.Net Web Form applications as there are multiple URLs that could map to a single place. Use the Authorize attribute instead.

Also check my response here:
[What features do I need to have before I open an ASP.Net app onto the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738846/what-features-do-i-need-to-have-before-i-open-an-asp-net-app-onto-the-internet/5739032#5739032)

In addition make sure you use Html.AntoForgeryToken in your views and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on your [HttpPost] controller methods (ie any methods you post back to)